# HTTP post method doesn't work in IE11

Tags: angularjs, http, asp.net-web-api, internet-explorer-11, angular-resource

I am trying to send a HTTP Post method from IE11 but it's not working. When Fiddler is open it detects a protocol violation: "Content-Length mismatch : Request header indicates X bytes, but client sent 0 bytes". It's working on Chrome, and I can't find a reason why it won't work in the IE11. I make the call using angular resource (In case it matters).

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm quite sure that POST isn't broken altoghether in IE11. Show your code.

Comment: Is it cross-domain request?

Comment: It is not cross domain. The code is:`[HttpPost]public void SaveUser(User user){userDataAccess.SaveUser(user);}`

Answer (score 0):

Me and my friends realized what the problem is. IE Has a problem with `location.reload(true)` for an unknown reason. Instead we injected angular's `$route` and reloaded the page using the function `$route.reload()`